# WP_Post Object vs stdClass Object

Tags: php, wordpress, stdclass

I have two results , one with `WP_Post` Object and other is `stdClass` Object. All contains same data. How do I differentiate them?

Result 1 :-

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 952
    [post_content] =>  
    [post_title] => 
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => open
    [ping_status] => open
)
```

Result 2 : -

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ID] => 952
    [post_content] =>  
    [post_title] => 
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => open
    [ping_status] => open
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use instanceof

Like this:

```
if($obj instanceof WP_Post)
```

I am not sure if it is a valid approach, but I have seen this used in some plugins and projects. So as a possible approach it might work

Answer (score 2):

use get_class($object) to get the class name of an object and in your case it would return stdClass and WP_Post for both the respective objects

Refer php.net manual for more detail http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php